# How would I implement navmesh pathfinding into this AI following code. C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, navmesh

I have this code that makes the enemy follow my player(And attack etc) but im not sure how to add navmesh into this so it can navigate obstacles. Currently, it goes forward and gets stuck on walls and obstacles. 
I have never used navmesh before.

How would I implement navmesh pathfinding into this code.

Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class wheatleyfollow : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject ThePlayer;
    public float TargetDistance;
    public float AllowedRange = 500;
    public GameObject TheEnemy;
    public float EnemySpeed;
    public int AttackTrigger;
    public RaycastHit Shot;

    void Update() {
        transform.LookAt (ThePlayer.transform);
        if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward), out Shot)) {
            TargetDistance = Shot.distance;
            if (TargetDistance < AllowedRange) {
                EnemySpeed = 0.05f;
                if (AttackTrigger == 0) {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, ThePlayer.transform.position, EnemySpeed);
                }
            } else {
                EnemySpeed = 0;
            }
        }

        if (AttackTrigger == 1) {
            EnemySpeed = 0;
            TheEnemy.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("wheatleyattack");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter() {
        AttackTrigger = 1;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit() {
        AttackTrigger = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome good sir.  You might be better asking this over at the Unity forums or at [gamedev](http://gamedev.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off, we will require a `NavMeshAgent` on the object that will hold this script and we will then save a reference to the agent. We will also need a `NavMeshPath` to store our path (This isn't an attachable component, we will create it within the code).

All we need to do is update the path using `CalculatePath` and `SetPath`. You may need to fine tune the code some, but this is the very basics. You can use `CalculatePath` to generate a path then decide if you want to execute that path by using `SetPath`.

**Note:** We could use `SetDestination`, but if you have many AI units it can become slow if you need instant paths, which is why I normally use `CalculatePath` and `SetPath`.

Now all that is left is to make your navmesh `Window -> Navigation`. In there you can finetune your agents and areas. One required step is to bake your mesh in the `Bake` tab.

Unity supports navmeshes on components for prefabs and other things, however, these components are not yet built into Unity, as you will need to [download](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents) them into your project.

As you can see all of your speed and movement has been removed since it is now controlled by your `NavMeshAgent`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class wheatleyfollow : MonoBehaviour {

  public GameObject ThePlayer;
  public float TargetDistance;
  public float AllowedRange = 500;
  public GameObject TheEnemy;
  public int AttackTrigger;
  public RaycastHit Shot;

  private NavMeshAgent agent;
  private NavMeshPath path;

  void Start() {
    path = new NavMeshPath();
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
  }

  void Update() {
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out Shot)) {
      TargetDistance = Shot.distance;
      if (TargetDistance < AllowedRange && AttackTrigger == 0) {
        agent.CalculatePath(ThePlayer.transform.position, path);
        agent.SetPath(path);
      }
    }
    if (AttackTrigger == 1) {
      TheEnemy.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("wheatleyattack");
    }
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter() {
    AttackTrigger = 1;
  }

  void OnTriggerExit() {
    AttackTrigger = 0;
  }

}
```

**Side Note:** You should remove any `using`'s that you are not using, as this can bloat your final build.